# List stream does not filter correct

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have problem with List when I'm streaming. If I reduce stream then I get correct result, but if I filter stream and invoke *findFirst()* I get empty result. Why? What do I do wrong?

**Index** - contains data in map:

```
public class Index {

    private final Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    
    public String getData(String name) {
        return data.getOrDefault(name, "");
    }
    
    public Set<String> getDataNames() {
        return data.keySet();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return data.toString();
    }
}
```

**IndexList** - contains Index objects in list, filling is invoke *load()* method in *Main* class:

```
public enum IndexList {

    INDICES_0("First list", new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("name", "surname", "an")));

    private List<Index> loaded;
    private final String name;
    private final Queue<String> nameQueue;

    IndexList(String name, Queue<String> nameQueue) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nameQueue = nameQueue;
    }

    public Index get(int id) {
        return loaded.get(id-1);
    }

    public List<Index> getLoaded() {
        return loaded;
    }

    public void load() {
        this.loaded = new LinkedList<>();
        
        // ... > loading from xml file

        List<Index> loaded = this.loaded;
        this.loaded = new ArrayList<>(loaded);
        loaded.clear();
    }

    public Queue<String> queueNames() {
        return new LinkedList<>(nameQueue);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I normal run I saw some Index object should be show in GUI, but it did not. So I ran program in debugger and added watches.

**In debugger**:

```
IndexList.INDICES_0.loaded.size() = 558
IndexList.INDICES_0.loaded.stream().get(0) = {Index@1700} "{surname=Smith, name=John, an=1/2000}"
IndexList.INDICES_0.loaded.stream().reduce((i0, i1) -> i1.getData("surname").equals("Smith") && i1.getData("name").equals("John")? i1 : i0) = {Optional@1623} "Optional[{surname=Smith, name=John, an=1/2000}]"
IndexList.INDICES_0.loaded.stream().filter(i -> i.getData("surname").equals("Smith") && i.getData("name").equals("John")).findFirst() = {Optional@1640} "Optional.empty"
```

Comment: Remove `loaded.clear();`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It does not matter. I presented debugger result and it showed list correct.

Comment: Your pastes are incorrect; for example, line 3 of 'in debugger is missing a closing paren. If you fix that, it's an operation that turns 2 Index objects into a boolean, which would be a compilation error; you need to pass into 'reduce' a function that turns 2 Index objects into one Index object. This makes your question unanswerable.

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: I forgot closing paren and corrected this, @rzwitserloot.

Comment: I cannot present full code, because it is too big. I can share necessary fragments to you, @tgdavies.

Comment: As @rzwitserloot pointed out, your reduce function cannot be correct. Please update your question with actual code.

Comment: I've already done that.

Comment: You need to create a simpler version of your code, then, which can demonstrate the problem—a [mre].  I’m guessing your actual code doesn’t hard-code "surname" and "Smith", so I would first check whether the strings you use in your filter are in fact what they should be.  We can’t do that because we don’t know how you’re obtaining or building those strings.

Comment: [GitHub Repository of fully classes](https://github.com/koder95/eMetrykant/tree/core/src/main/java/pl/koder95/eme/dfs). I cannot simplify this well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved problem: in set of strings were **UTF-8 BOM** characters and the same surnames was in different places.
So, *reduce method* returned the first object in stream.